# How to clear a page on user clicking a image and calculate output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a rock paper scissor website i have made a webpage with three image [JSFIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tn9Kj/4/embedded/result)! i want to call a function on click of the image which clears the webpage displays what is the computers choice and also display whether the useer has won or not the javascript code i am gonna use is

```
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare=function(choice1,choice2)
{
    if(choice1==choice2){
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }
    if(choice1=="rock")
    {
        if(choice2=="scissors")
        {return "rock wins";}
        else if(choice2=="paper")
        {return "paper wins";}
    }
    if(choice1=="paper")
    {
        if(choice2=="scissors")
        {return "scissors wins";}
        else if(choice2=="rock")
        {return "paper wins";}
    }
 if(choice1=="scissors")
    {
        if(choice2=="paper")
        {return "scissors wins";}
        else if(choice2=="rock")
        {return "rock wins";}
    }
};

compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
```

Comment: No HTML. Do we guess? And a jsfiddle with no JS. Please sort your question out.

Comment: Using jquery you can do this ( http://jsfiddle.net/pjLaq/ ). Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @ssBarBee hey you rock it is extremely good but i also want to show some images during the result

Comment: Feel free to update the code with images then:)

Comment: @ssBarBee but how to add images i don 't know i am a newbie

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle that will get you started - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tn9Kj/17/)

I'll work on a different approach using numbers instead of text that might shorten the code, but it will take me a day or two.

```
    $( 'img' ).on('click', function(){
  var userChoice = this.id;
  var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34)
       {
        computerChoice = "rock";
        }
         else if(computerChoice <= 0.67)
       {
        computerChoice = "paper";
        }
         else
       {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
        }
        console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

  compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
//---------------------------------------------------
});

var compare=function(choice1,choice2)
{
    if( choice1==choice2 )
    {
        return "Tie!";
     }
    if( choice1=="rock" )
    {
     if(choice2=="scissors")
        {
          $('.putmehere').html( "rock wins" );
         }
        else if(choice2=="paper")
        {
         $('.putmehere').html( "paper wins" );
         }
     }
    if(choice1=="paper")
      {
       if(choice2=="scissors")
         {
          $('.putmehere').html( "Scissors wins" );
          }
          else if(choice2=="rock")
         {
          $('.putmehere').html( "rock wins" );
         }
          }
     if(choice1=="scissors")
       {
        if(choice2=="paper")
        {
         return $('.putmehere').html( "scissors wins" );
         }
         else if(choice2=="rock")
        {
         $('.putmehere').html( "rock wins" );
         }
        }
};
```